# Как можно расширить системный диск Windows?

Tags: windows

Всем привет, как расширить системный диск, я пытался отрезать часть от своего диска E и закинуть к диску С, но пункт меню расширить для него не активный
[image: Вот диски]

Comment: 1) Поджать E:. С головы. 2) Подвинуть Healthy. 3) Раздвинуть C:. PS. Штатные средства двигать "голову" вроде как не умеют. PPS. Проще забэкапить полностью, а потом восстановить с изменением размеров.

Comment: @Akina можно пожалуйста чуть подробнее

Comment: Можно попробовать преобразовать Disk 0  в динамический. Только учтите, что делая что-то с дисками, вы рискуете как минимум поломать загрузку, как максимум - потерять данные.

Comment: Можно и подробнее. Делаем полный бэкап и прячем - вдруг что пойдёт не так. Берём достаточно продвинутую программу по работе с разделами. Уменьшаем размер раздела Е с головы - чтобы освобождённое место было между ним и предыдущим Recovery-разделом. Применяем. Проверяем, что всё на месте и работает. Перемещаем Recovery (508M) вплотную к Е. Применяем. Проверяем. Растягиваем С на свободное пространство. Применяем. Проверяем. Минимум месяц не удаляем бэкап - вдруг что вылезет...